# How can I tell if a static object has been destroyed in C++11

Tags: c++11, destructor, exit

In the C++11 specification, basic.start.term 1 states:

> If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization of an object with static storage
>   duration is sequenced before that of another, the completion of the destructor of the second is sequenced
>   before the initiation of the destructor of the first. [ Note: This definition permits concurrent destruction.
>   —end note ]

In C++03, my destructors were ordered.  The order may not be specified, but they were ordered.  This was very useful for static objects that had to register themselves.  There was no concept of multithreading in the spec, so the spec had no concept of unordered destructors.  The compilers that implemented multithreading that I know of did destruction in a single-threaded environment.

```
a.cpp:
  struct A
  {
       A()
       : mRegistration(0)
       { }

       ~A()
       {
           if (mRegistration)
             tryUnregisterObject(mRegistration);
       }

       void registerNow()
       {
           mRegistration = registerObject(this);
       }
  };

  A myA;

b.cpp:


  class Registrar
  {
      public:
           Registrar()
           {
               isAlive = true;
           }
           ~Registrar()
           {
               isAlive = false;
           }
      ...
  };

  bool isAlive = false; // constant initialization
  static Registrar& registrar()
  {
      static Registrar instance;
      return instance;
  }

  int registerObject(void* obj)
  {
      registar().register(obj);
  }

  void tryUnregisterObject(void* obj)
  {
     if (isAlive) {
        registrar().unregister(obj);
     } else {
        // do nothing.  registrar was destroyed
     }
  }
```

In this example, I can't guarantee the order of destruction for `myA` and `Registrar` because they're in different compilation units.  However, I can at least detect what order they occurred in and act accordingly.

In C++11, this approach creates a data race around the `isAlive` variable.  This can be solved during construction because I can create a synchronization object like a mutex to protect it when I first need it.  However, in the destruction case, I may have to check isAlive after my mutex has been destroyed!

Is there a way to get around this in C++11?  I feel like I need a synchronization primitive to solve the problem, but everything I've tried leads to the primitive getting destroyed before its done protecting what I need to protect.  If I were to use the Windows or PThreads threading primitives, I could simply elect to not call the destructor and let the OS clean up after me.  However, C++ objects clean themselves up.

Comment: I'm guessing "avoid statics" is not an acceptable answer... :)

Comment: Can your objects which need registration have an additional member which contains a shared_ptr to something ... e.g., the deregistration singleton?  Then the shared_ptr semantics will control the lifetime of the deregistration object.  That should be safe?

Comment: Plus, if you do need a synchronization primitive you can build one out of atomics - or perhaps there's one already available - that because it does not actually get destructed is safe to use in any order ...

Answer (score 0):

> **[basic.start.init]/2** If a program starts a thread (30.3), the subsequent initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is **indeterminately sequenced** with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. If a program starts a thread, the subsequent unordered initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization. Otherwise, the unordered initialization of a variable is **indeterminately sequenced** with respect to every other dynamic initialization.

(Emphasis mine.) Therefore, as long as you don't start threads in any of your static objects' constructors, you have the same guarantee as in earlier versions of the standard.

Comment: Counter-example: Before the possibility of concurrent destruction means that if you have 2 static objects which somehow share a resource, previously you could use a simple counter to decide which of the static destructors should destroy the shared object, even though the sequencing was indeterminate. With concurrent destruction, that counter would be required to at least be atomic.

Comment: @GemTaylor If there wasn't concurrent construction, there shouldn't be concurrent destruction either, per **[basic.start.term]/1** quoted in the question.